# How do I add ts comment to typescript string literal union type ？

Tags: typescript

I have one string literal union type like this:

```
type Text = 'AAAA' | 'BBBB' | 'CCCC'
```

now,I want to comment out each string literal type,What should I do？
I did that before, but it was wrong：

```
type Text = /** this is A */ 'AAAA' | /** this is B */ 'BBBB' | /** this is C */ 'CCCC'
```

Comment: Why do you want to add a comment in the middle of code. Don't mix comment with executable code. `Add comment first next line write code` is standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to use leading pipe `|` in typescript for unions:

```js
type MyText =
  | /** this is A */ 'AAAA'
  | /** this is B */ 'BBBB'
  | /** this is C */ 'CCCC'
```